# Query collection and get list of values as field postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, collections

I don't know if the query I'm trying to do is even possible so I was hoping you could give me some ideas of how to manage this problem.

I have 3 tables that I will call book, magazine and magazine_collection.

```
book: (shared_book_id, title, fields...)
magazine: (shared_book_id, magazine_collection_id, fields...)
magazine_collection: (magazine_collection_id, name, fields...)
```

I would like to retrieve in a single query all magazine_collections and a list of all the books that relates to them.

Example:

```
book: [{shared_book_id: 1, title: 'Title1'}, 
       {shared_book_id: 2, title: 'Title2'}, 
       {shared_book_id: 3, title: 'Title3'},
       {shared_book_id: 4, title: 'Title4'}]

 magazine[{shared_book_id: 2, magazine_collection_id: 1},
          {shared_book_id: 4, magazine_collection_id: 1}]

 magazine_collection[{magazine_collection_id: 1, name: 'Collection1']
```

After the query runs I expect:

```
[{magazine_collection_id: 1, name: 'Collection1', 
 books: [{shared_book_id: 2, title: 'Title2'}, 
         {shared_book_id: 4, title: 'Title4'}, ...]
```

I thought about doing something like this but obviously there is my most important function missing, also I don't how I can pass the id of the collection I'm currently on to the query that runs behind it.

```
SELECT mc, (X_FUNCTION) AS books 
      FROM magazine_collection mc 
      JOIN magazine m ON mc.shared_book_id = m.shared_book_id 
      JOIN book b ON m.shared_book_id = b.shared_book_id
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql there is a function for this specific case named array https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html.

A solution for this case would have been:

```
SELECT mc, ARRAY(SELECT b.shared_id_book FROM book b JOIN magazine m ON 
m.shared_id_book = b.shared_id_book WHERE m.magazine_collection_id = 
mc.magazine_collection_id) as books FROM magazine_collection mc;
```